# Present tense to emphasize the fact that it would not change

Tags: grammar

I know that the eternal truth has to be written in the present tense. For example,

> Lulu explained that the sun is very hot.

Could I say something like this?:

> I told you that he doesn't like the coke.

The fact that he likes coke is not the eternal truth as he might change his mind someday. However, to emphasize the fact that it is very unlikely for him to change his opinion, could I express it as the present tense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

When we say that the present tense is used for "eternal truths", we don't mean that literally. When I explain it to people, I usually don't say "eternal truth" but something more like "things that are true now and that we expect to be true indefinitely".

Your example is, in fact, an excellent example. People very regularly say things like, "I don't like Coke." Meaning, I don't like Coke now and I expect to continue not liking it indefinitely.

We very often say things like, "The capital of France is Paris." Does this mean that we suppose that France will always exist for the rest of Eternity and that's its capital will always be Paris and that there are no imaginable circumstances under which they might move the capital to some other city? No. We just mean that that's the capital now and we have no reason to believe it will change any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, at the current time, an for the foreseeable future, it is true that he does not like coke, so you can definitely use present simple.

Your sentence is grammatically correct and idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that he still doesn't like coke then it is totally fine. Otherwise, you can change it to:

```
I told you that he didn't like the coke.
```